# Conjugates of an element in algebraic number fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$. Then by primitive element theorem there exist a $\theta \in K$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. Let $\theta_1 = \theta, \theta_2, \dots \theta_n$ be the conjugates of $\theta$ over rational numbers (i.e. roots of minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which is satisfied by $\theta$). Since any $\alpha \in K$ can be written uniquely as
$$ \alpha = c_0  + c_1 \theta + \cdots c_{n-1} \theta ^ {n-1}$$ for some rational numbers $c_i ( i =1, 2, ...,n)$. Let
$$ \alpha_k = c_0 + c_1 \theta_k + \cdots + c_{n-1}\theta_k^{n-1}$$ for $k = 1,2,\dots ,n$

We call $\{ \alpha_k \, \vert k = 1 , 2 \dots , n \}$ as $K$-conjugates of $\alpha $.

Our claim is that

> $K$-conjugates of $\alpha $ does not depend on $\theta$ for all $k =1,2, \dots n$

Since there exist $\phi \ne \theta $ in $K$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\phi)$, there are unique rational numbers $d_1, \dots d_{n-1}$ such that $\alpha = d_0 + \cdots d_{n-1} \phi^{n-1} $. Now let $\phi_1 = \phi , \phi_2 ,\dots \phi_n$ be conjugates of $\phi$ over rational numbers. Let $\beta_1 = \alpha$ and $$ \beta _ k = d_0 + d_1 \phi_k + \cdots + d_{n-1} \phi_k^{n-1} $$
for $k = 2, \dots , n$.

If we can show that $\beta_k$ are permutation of $\alpha_k$ we are done.

This is easy to see in some examples, consider $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$. Let $\theta = \sqrt 2, \phi = 5 + \sqrt 2$ and $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt 2$. Since the $\sqrt 2$ satisfies the equation $x^2 - 2 = 0$ we have $\theta_1 = \sqrt 2, \theta _ 2 = - \sqrt 2$. Similarly $\phi_1 = 5 + \sqrt 2 $ and $\phi_2 = 5 - \sqrt 2$.
Now we have $\alpha_1 = 1 +\sqrt 2$ and $\alpha_2 =  1 - \sqrt 2$. Since we can write
$$ \alpha = -4 + (5 + \sqrt 2)$$
we have $\beta_1 =  \alpha_1 = 1 + \sqrt 2$ and $\beta_2 = -4 + (5 - \sqrt 2) = 1 - \sqrt 2 = \alpha_2 $ which fits with out hypothesis.

**Attempt to prove:**

Initially I thought expressing each $\phi_k ^ m $ as a linear combination of $1, \theta_k, ^2  \dots , \theta_k ^ {n-1}$ and then try to write $\beta_k$ in terms of power of $\theta_k$ and finally show that corresponding coefficients and $c_i$ are equal. But I could not finish this.

I also tried another method which I include as an answer because it is too long to fit here.

But in the above example it appears that $\alpha_k = \beta_k$ for all $k$.I am not sure whether this is true in general. If any other approaches are known it will be helpful. Hints are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_{\alpha}(x)$ be the monic, minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Consider two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that
$$f(x) = (x - \alpha_1) \cdots (x - \alpha_n)$$ and $$g(x) = (x - \beta_1) \cdots (x - \beta_n)$$

We claim that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. We first observe that $f(x)$ is a symmetric polynomial in terms of $\theta_1, \dots \theta_n$. By fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials we know that $f(x)$ is a symmetric polynomial in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials in terms of $\theta_1, \dots \theta_n$. But elementary symmetric polynomials are coefficients of minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ so they are rational numbers. Hence $f(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. A similar argument shows that $g(x)$ is a polynomial over rational numbers.

We observe that $f(\alpha) = 0$ so that $f_{\alpha}(x) \vert f(x)$. So there exist a $h(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that

$$f(x) = f_{\alpha}(x) ^ s h(x)$$ since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an *UFD* where $h(x)$ does not divide $f_{\alpha}(x)$ and $s$ is a positive integer .

We claim that $h(x)$ is constant polynomial.

If it is not a constant polynomial then there exist a $k$ such that $h(\alpha_k) = 0$. Consider the polynomial $r(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \cdots + c_{n-1} x^{n-1}$ so that $\alpha = r(\theta)$. Now we see that $h(r(\theta_k)) = h(\alpha_k) = 0$ so that $f_{\theta_k}(x)$ divides $h(r(x))$. But it is well-known that $f_{\theta_k}(x) = f_{\theta}(x)$. So that $h(r(\theta)) = h(\alpha) = 0$ which implies that $h(x)$ divides $f_{\alpha}(x)$ which is a contradiction. So $h(x)$ is a constant. Since $f_{\alpha}(x)$ and $f(x)$ are monic and so is $h(x)$. So we have $h(x) = 1$. So
$$ f(x) = f_{\alpha}(x)^s$$
Similarly there exist a positive integer $t$ such that
$$g(x) = f_{\alpha}(x)^t$$

Since $\deg f = \deg g = n$ we must have $s =t $. So we have

$$ (x- \alpha_1) \cdots (x-\alpha_n) = (x - \beta_1) \cdots (x- \beta_n)$$ which is sufficient to conclude that $\alpha_i$s are permutation of $\beta_i$s since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a *UFD*.

Any improvements to this post are welcome.

Comment: I like your answer which is a bit easier to understand. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'd think of this as follows. Write $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n\colon K\hookrightarrow\mathbb C$ for the field embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb C$. If we fix $\sigma_1$ to be an initial embedding (so that we can view $K\subset\mathbb C$), and let $\theta\in K\subset\mathbb C$ be a primitive element, then it's clear that the elements $\sigma_k(\theta)$ all have the same minimal polynomial as $\theta$. Thus, up to reordering, we can take $\theta_k = \sigma_k(\theta)$.

If $\alpha = \sum c_i\theta^i$, then $\alpha_k$ is just $\sigma_k(\alpha)$. Since the definition of $\sigma_k$ has nothing to do with $\theta$, we see that $\alpha_k=\sigma_k(\alpha)$ does not depend on $\theta$.

The upshot is that you should think of the $K$-conjugates of an element $\alpha\in K$ as being the $\sigma_k(\alpha)$ rather than elements of $\mathbb C$ with the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$. Both definitions are equivalent, but the former allows you to use field arithmetic!

Comment: Don't you think that we need to show there are only $n$ distinct field embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$? Is it trivial?

Comment: It's a standard fact. But here's a simple proof: choose a primitive element $\theta$. If $\theta'$ is another root of its minimal polynomial, then the map $K = \mathbb Q(\theta) \to \mathbb Q(\theta')\subset\mathbb C$ defines an embedding $K\to \mathbb C$. There are $n$ of these (and they're distinct because the minimal polynomial is irreducible and hence separable). Of course you then have to check that the set of embeddings does not depend on $\theta$, so in some sense maybe my answer is a bit circular.

Comment: But if $\phi$ is another primitive element with minimal polynomial $h$, and  if $\sigma:K\to \mathbb C$ is an embedding defined using $\theta$, then $h(\sigma(\phi)) = \sigma(h(\phi)) = 0$. So $\sigma(\phi)$ is another root of $h$. So everything is well-defined. I still think this approach is significantly easier (and more intuitive) than working with symmetric polynomials!! The point is that we're using the arithmetic of fields, not just the properties of polynomials.

Comment: So it is sufficient to show that any embedding of $K$ into $C$ is one of those which we have defined. I think this proves that embeddings are independent of $\theta$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct! The point is that if $f$ is irreducible, an embedding takes a root of $f$ to another root of $f$ just because field embeddings permute with polynomials.